# Find conditional probability (′|′)

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this task but I'm obviously stuck.  Can anybody help me how to solve this ?

If ()=1/6, ()=1/3 , and (∪)=5/12, what is (′|′)?

Comment: Use De-Morgan to turn the $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$ into something that is related to $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @YJT's comment, we can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A^{c}|B^{c}) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B^{c})}{\mathbb{P}(B^{c})} = \frac{\mathbb{P}((A\cup B)^{c})}{\mathbb{P}(B^{c})} = \frac{1 - \mathbb{P}(A\cup B)}{1 - \mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{1-5/12}{1 - 1/3} = \frac{7}{8}
\end{align*}